# dynamic multi-dimentional array on class

Tags: c++, class

I need to define an array of two dimensions at class, the array should be dynamic, and during the program I need to use copy constructor to copy this array to another array in case we want to enlarge the lines or the columns.

How should I define this array, I add the header file I got but I don't know how to define the array at the header or should I define it at the cpp file?

```
typedef int   size_type;
typedef int** grid_type;

class Map
{

private:
    grid_type ppGrid;
    size_type size_h;
    size_type size_w;

};
```

Comment: In C++, a "dynamic array" is usually `std::vector`.

Comment: *I need to use copy constructor to copy this array to a nother array in case we want to enlarge the lines or the columns* is not very clear to me. How could a true copy constructor change the lines or columns ?

Comment: I would use a vector but in this case I was asked to you arrays and not vectors. the copy consturctor won't choose the lines, I need to you build an array that gets 0 or 1 in each cell, in case the user decided to enlarge the array the value in each cell won't change, and this why I thought using copy constructor.